# Name of non-relation

Tags: logic, terminology

I remember studying in the book "[User interface design](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=83824)" by Harold Thimbleby the property I describe here. My question is: **What is the name of this property?** I want to *find* it but can't, because I don't even have a name for it.

> The properties of the elements not necessarily transfer to the set of the elements.

Example:

- a judge can express a verdict (decide yes or no);
- an odd number of judges can express the verdict of the majority;
- an even number of judges can, under circumstances, not express a verdict.

Say, you have 4 judges and 2 decide for *yes* while the other two decide for *no*. In this case no majority is reached, thus, the group cannot decide.

In the example, the property "a judge can decide" does not transfer to "a group of judges can decide". Obviously, several conditions have to be met so that the "can decide" property may NOT transfer from the element (judge) to the set (group of judges).

What is the name of this non-transitivity from elements to sets of homogenous elements?

In computer-speech:

```
If every element E in S satisfies predicate P(E),
then P(S) is still NOT NECESSARILY satisfied.
```

Maybe the otherway around is more common and you can simply say "it does not hold":

```
If every element E in S satisfies predicate P(E),
then P(S) is necessarily satisfied.
```

Maybe this last expression is what you may know, and all I have to do is say "this transitivity cannot be applied"?

---

**EDIT:** new example

Say you can only see two colors: black and white.

A marble has a color (black or white), but a group of marbles has not necessarily a color:

- all marble black -> set is black
- all marbles white -> set is white
- mixed black/white -> set has no color

Maybe this explains a bit better what kind of *transitivity* I intend. From the elements to the set of elements.

---

**EDIT 2: GOT IT!**

It's the **FALLACY OF COMPOSITION** as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_composition).
Someone close this question, looks like I don't have the necessary permissions to do so.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA nitpicking ahead: a transitive set is one such that the membership relation is transitive over its elements, so I think that it is aptly named.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: No it's not the same as "transitive set". He wants to go from elements having a property to the set having the property, not the other way around.

Comment: @Jsevillamol: Nitpickers flock together.. A set $x$ is transitive iff the membership relation is transitive on $x \cup {x}$.

Comment: I found the name, thanks to everybody!

Comment: What you should do is post the resolution you found as an answer to your old question. After 2 days (I think) you will be able to accept your own answer, thereby marking the question as resolved.

Comment: The question and the OP's resolution of it are outside the scope of MSE and have zero mathematical interest. So I vote to close the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has asked so.

Comment: @Shailesh:  The OP did not ask to close the question because it is off-topic, but rather because they found an answer.  This is a misunderstanding of the practice, easily attributed to inexperience.  My view is that the Question presents several possible applications of this fallacy in mathematical reasoning and thus creates the nexus to make the post on-topic.

Comment: @hardmath Accepted...Vote retracted.